# Recognition of a function input by filter in R?

Tags: r, function, dplyr, tidyverse, rlang

In my `foo()` call below, is there a way for the input of `filter_var =` (i.e., `test`) to be recognized inside the function?

Right now, the input is not recognized.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rlang)

foo <- function(..., filter_var = NULL){

filter_var <- rlang::ensyms(filter_var)
  
dat <- expand_grid(...)  

dat %>%
filter(
  
    {{filter_var}} != "A"   ## HERE `filter_var` is not recognized. 
  )
}

foo(study = 1:2, test = LETTERS[1:2], filter_var = test)

#  study test 
#  <int> <chr>
#1     1 A    
#2     1 B    
#3     2 A    
#4     2 B
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't combine `ensym` and `{{}}`. Either use `{{}}` without the explict `ensym`

```
foo <- function(..., filter_var = NULL){
  dat <- expand_grid(...)  
  dat %>%
    filter({{filter_var}} != "A")
}

foo(study = 1:2, test = LETTERS[1:2], filter_var = test)
```

or use `!!` with the `ensym` (note that you're only decoding one symbol so use `ensym` rather than `ensyms`).

```
foo <- function(..., filter_var = NULL){
  filter_var <- rlang::ensym(filter_var)
  dat <- expand_grid(...)  
  dat %>%
    filter(!!filter_var != "A")
}
```